# how to enable sudo for one directory

Tags: permissions, rhel, sudo

I have `Redhat` 6.3 and I want to enable `sudo` command for `chown`,`kill` and `chmod`, so under root user I did the following:

```
visudo
#add the following line
aabuhasna ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/kill, /bin/chmod, /bin/chown
```

Based on the added line user `aabuhasna` can do `chmod`, and `chown` on any directory or file, but I want to restrict that for one directory for example
if I use the command `chown aabuhasna:aabuhasna /test_dir/*` it work but if I use `chown aabuhasna:aabuhasna /opt/*` it fail, the same goes for `chmod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards with sudo commands are a bit dicey. They can appear to give you security without actually doing so. To `sudo`, the `*` *does not mean* "any files under this directory" as it does in the shell. Rather, it means "any additional options" and must stand alone. Unfortunatley, you cannot in sudo restrict part of the arguments, and further, it wouldn't be secure (because the user can specify `../../` which would foil your intentions).

So here's what you do: write a script that carefully validates the command-line arguments and makes sure these don't contain things like `../`. Then that script is included in sudo for the user. One more point: bash is a poor choice in this context because of the numerous ways the malicious user can subvert your intent. So here is a perl Example which I've tested and should fit your needs (after customization, and replacing `echo` with the empty-string).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $user = "aabuhasna";
my $group = "aabuhasna";
my $prefix = "/test_dir";

$mode=shift @ARGV or die "Please provide a mode for the new file";
die "Invalid chmod input: $mode" unless $mode =~ /^[0-9]+$/;
$mode = oct($mode);
die "Invalid permissions in mode: $mode" if $mode != ($mode & 0777);
my $uid = (getpwnam($owner))[2] or die "Unknown user: $user";
my $gid = (getpwnam($group))[2] or die "Unknown group: $group";
foreach (@ARGV) {
   die "Invalid Directory Argument: $_" if m:\.\./:;
   next if -l $prefix."/".$_;
   push @files,$prefix."/".$_;
}
die "No files specified!" unless @files;

chmod $mode, @files;
chown $uid, @gid, @files;
```

The sudo entry for this script, let's say you put it in `/usr/local/bin/changemodeowner` is simple:

```
aabuhasna ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/changemodeowner
```

No `*` needed here.

Comment: If the user needs to do a large number of files in that directory, they can use find, pipe to xargs which runs the script via sudo . So `find /test_dir -name "*.htm" -size +1 | xargs sudo /usr/local/bin/changemodeowner 0644 ` should work to get all files ending in `.htm` and not empty.

Comment: Very nice. I just knew I should have gone for the scripted approach.

Comment: Nice of you to give me root on your machine! There was at least one glaring bug in this script — try invoking it with the argument `;sh`. I fixed that one in an edit. And note that the permissions can escape the directory if there are symbolic links there that do. Cc @roaima

Comment: Oh my! I've gotten quite rusty. Thanks a bunch, @Gilles! :)

Comment: @roaima I added a test for soft-links. (BTW: The map command is "cooler" but never as flexible as good-ol' foreach)

Comment: `ln /etc/passwd /test_dir` if on same partition